# ZBar - Attempting to read PDF417 codes

Tags: c, webassembly, zbar, pdf417

I am attempting to make a [PDF417](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417) barcode reader for the web using Web Assembly (there's a few out there but the only reliable one is licenced). The idea is simple, just build a binary file with C code that can be called via JavaScript.

I followed [this guide](https://barkeywolf.consulting/posts/barcode-scanner-webassembly/) which got me almost there! I had to add `--enable-codes=pdf417` as a parameter to `configure` to enable PDF417 symbols and disable all the others I'm not interested in.

The code actually works amazingly well for any other type of symbol ([see demo](https://barkeywolf.consulting/barcode-scanner-webassembly-demo/index.html)) but if I compile ZBar to accept PDF417, it detects it but throws a warning:

```
WARNING: zbar/decoder/pdf417.c:73: pdf417_decode8: Assertion "clst >= 0 && clst < 9" failed.
dir=0 sig=5a44 k=9 buf[0000]=

WARNING: zbar/decoder/pdf417.c:89: pdf417_decode8: Assertion "g[0] >= 0 && g[1] >= 0 && g[2] >= 0" failed.
dir=1 sig=ca03 k=6 g0=ffffffff g1=e71 g2=585 buf[0000]=
```

Those assertions are on lines [71](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/blob/master/zbar/decoder/pdf417.c#L71) and [86](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/blob/master/zbar/decoder/pdf417.c#L86) of ZBar.

You can see all the code I'm using in the guide I mentioned earlier (the only difference is that I enabled PDF417 before compiling) ¿Any ideas?

Comment: I am stuck in the same boat... were you able to find something on this?

Comment: Sorry, no. There's hundreds of ZBar forks and clones out there. I consulted in some of the more actives ones and none seem to have completed PDF417 decoding. https://github.com/mchehab/zbar/issues/3

Comment: Saw your note, you mentioned you used cpp port for zxing. I tried that as well but it does not work well with streaming :( Were you able to work with streaming video?

Comment: Sure. Check it out here: https://github.com/Naahuel/poc-dni-pdf417-WA
It's not super efficient but it works. It converts the video stream to canvas and then parses that. Also take a look at this issue where they give suggestions to make the binary wasm file a bit smaller https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp/issues/40

Answer (score 3):

The default behaviour of zbar is to attempt to decode all [symbol types](https://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/code/ci/default/tree/zbar/decoder.c#l487).

```
if(sym == ZBAR_NONE) {
    static const zbar_symbol_type_t all[] = {
    ZBAR_EAN13, ZBAR_EAN2, ZBAR_EAN5, ZBAR_EAN8,
        ZBAR_UPCA, ZBAR_UPCE, ZBAR_ISBN10, ZBAR_ISBN13,
        ZBAR_I25, ZBAR_DATABAR, ZBAR_DATABAR_EXP, ZBAR_CODABAR,
    ZBAR_CODE39, ZBAR_CODE93, ZBAR_CODE128, ZBAR_QRCODE, 
    ZBAR_PDF417, 0
    };
    const zbar_symbol_type_t *symp;
    for(symp = all; *symp; symp++)
        zbar_decoder_set_config(dcode, *symp, cfg, val);
    return(0);
}
```

Does your images contain PDF417 barcodes? If not, you could instruct zbar to decode just the symbol types of that are of interest to you, so the PF417 decoder will not be run. You do this using the symbols argument e.g., if your images contain just QR codes,

```
// disable all
scanner.set_config(ZBAR_NONE, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 0);

// enable qr
scanner.set_config(ZBAR_QRCODE, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 1);
```

in pyzbar

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import ZBarSymbol
decode(Image.open('pyzbar/tests/qrcode.png'), symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])
```

Comment: You seem to have copied this answer without attribution from the pyzbar github repo: https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/29

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to use ZBar for reading PDF417, [PDF417 decoding is incomplete](https://github.com/mchehab/zbar/issues/3). It will not work. Your best open source bet is ZXing.